# Non-blocking connect() with WinSocks

Tags: c++, winsock2

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625(VS.85).aspx) you have to create a non-blocking socket like this:

```cplusplus
unsigned nonblocking = 1;
ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &nonblocking);
```

and use it in the write-fdset for `select()` after that. To check if the connection was successful, you have to see if the socket is writeable. However, the MSDN-article does not describe how to check for errors.

How can I see if `connect()` did *not* succeed, and if that is the case, *why* it did not succeed?

Comment: The page you have linked to doesn't appear to be the correct one. I can't see any info about blocking sockets there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check socket error with `getsockopt()`. Here's a snippet from Stevens (granted it's Unix, but winsock should have something similar):

```
if ( FD_ISSET( sockfd, &rset ) || FD_ISSET( sockfd, &wset )) {
    len = sizeof(error);
    if ( getsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len ) < 0 )
        return -1;
} else {
    /* error */
}
```

Now `error` gives you the error number, if any.